# $(this).text() excludes text after space

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.ed_name').replaceWith(function() {
  return '<input placeholder=' + $(this).text() + ' value=' + $(this).html() + ' class="ed_inp">'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ed_name">Akshay Verma(Aks)</li>
</ul>
```

It returns only "Akshay" not "Akshay Verma(Aks)". I tried `.html()` method also.
can anyone answer why this is happening??

Comment: what is expected outcome?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`jQuery( html, attributes )`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) to create HTML elements, it will save you from quotes mess and potential issues.

```js
$('.ed_name').replaceWith(function() {
  return $('<input />', {
    "placeholder": $(this).text(),
    "value": $(this).html(),
    "class": "ed_inp"
  });

  //'<input placeholder="' + $(this).text() + '" value="' + $(this).html() + '" class="ed_inp">'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ed_name">Akshay Verma(Aks)</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attribute values aren’t quoted, so they’ll end at a space. Here’s half a fix:

```
$('.ed_name').replaceWith(function () {
    return '<input placeholder="'+$(this).text()+'" value="'+$(this).html()+'" class="ed_inp">'
});
```

but the right way is to create an element, not HTML:

```
$('.ed_name').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<input />', {
        placeholder: $(this).text(),
        value: $(this).html(),
        class: 'ed_inp',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget double quote in your input :

```js
$('.ed_name').replaceWith(function () {
    return '<input placeholder="'+$(this).text()+'" value="'+$(this).html()+'" class="ed_inp">'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="ed_name">Akshay Verma(Aks)</li>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using stack snippets over jsfiddle links

Answer (score 0):

Your code works exactly the way it should.  `$('.ed_name')` refers to the list item (`<li></li>`) and the `.text()` of that is `Akshay Verma(Aks)`